# ConstraintViolationTransactionFailureException when deleting all nodes from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When attempting to delete all nodes from my Neo4j graph database, which I have successfully done many times in the past on smaller datasets, I consistently ran across `Error: undefined - undefined` after running this query

`MATCH (n) DETACH
DELETE n`

I figured the number of nodes I was attempting to delete at once may be too large (>100000), so I then tried this query

`MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WITH n,r LIMIT 10000
DELETE n,r`

and many variations of it, acting on mostly what I read in this post: [Best way to delete all nodes and relationships in Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711757/best-way-to-delete-all-nodes-and-relationships-in-cypher/29715865). All returned this error

`org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ConstraintViolationTransactionFailureException: Cannot delete node<32769>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.`

and each time, the node Neo4j could not delete differs. Is there any way of resolving this issue?

Perhaps also noteworthy, while desperately running variations of the previous query, when I ran this query

`MATCH ()-[r]-()
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
WITH r,n LIMIT 10000
DELETE r,n`

I got this rather unique error

`Java heap space`

in the console, which showed up as `Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError` in the banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with the way your queries are written is that each `DELETE` is only attempting to delete a single node/relationship pair at a time. If any nodes have more than one relationship, you will get that constraint violation error, since in order to delete a node you have to delete all of its relationships (either beforehand or at the same time).

To delete 10000 nodes (and all their relationships), use this query:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n LIMIT 10000
DETACH DELETE n;
```

Comment: Yep, you got it. My second query works perfectly when I throw a DETACH in front of the DELETE, and I was able to delete nodes in increments of 50000.