# Unable to delete nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I tried to delete nodes in neo4j using cypher query `MATCH (n:WORKGROUP) detach delete n RETURN count(n)` and getting the below error

```
{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound","message":"Node with id 46103 has been deleted in this transaction"}]}.
```

Some times it works some time its not.
So what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect `n` to be usable after you had deleted the entire DB.

Assuming that you wanted to know what the original node count was, try this instead:

```
MATCH (n:WORKGROUP)
WITH n, COUNT(n) AS c
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN c;
```

Comment: Then why it is working some time.? When the above query fails i used `MATCH (n:WORKGROUP)-[r]-(s)  delete r,n RETURN count(n)` to delete. Some time both are failing to delete.

Comment: The code may not always fail. Also see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644721/constraintviolationtransactionfailureexception-when-deleting-all-nodes-from-neo4/39645965#39645965).